Microphone audio got cut off when the output audio is loud
So I have an aws g4dn.2xlarge setup with Nice dcv and Ubuntu 20.04, the instance uses a virtual sound card that is not visible to Alsa or PulseAudio, but somehow it works fine most of the time. I have an obs recording both the input(virtual microphone) and output(dummy output), and I'm using the microphone to play Minecraft with simple voice chat.
Then one day I was reminded by my friend that my audio is being cut off sometimes, and I found out that the microphone audio(both the one my friend heard and the one recorded in OBS) is cut off when there is loud noise from Minecraft(zombie screaming, ender man chasing you or even just opening the chest). I first thought this was an audio issue, but after I monitored the CPU usage using htop, the CPU (I have 8 cores, virtual, maybe Xeon) load is never above 70% during the gameplay and none of the cores is fully occupied, and the PulseAudio is not using much CPU as well. The same goes for memory.
So any idea how to fix this, without pulseaudio or alsa detecting the audio device (or better question maybe, how to let pulseaudio or alsa detect that virtual microphone? It's being recognize in the simple voice chat mod)
